# Не работает псевдоэлемент after

Tags: html, css

У обертки инпутов не появляются псевдоэлементы, но работают на остальной странице, прикреплю скриншот конечного результата и код блока.

Являюсь новичком и буду рад любым советам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.header__bottom__wrapper {
  height: 6.5rem;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__bottom {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__bottom__title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__bottom__title span {
  color: #9fb0c0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.header__bottom__title h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.header__bottom__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__bottom__content span {
  margin-right: 1.5625rem;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #8293a4;
}

.header__bottom__content input {
  padding-left: 0.5625rem;
  height: 2.9375rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #8a8a8a;
}

.header__bottom__content a {
  padding: 1.0625rem 1.5rem 1.0625rem 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 1.625rem;
  background-color: #1dd2af;
}

.header__bottom__content a:active {
  background-color: #1baf92;
  border-color: #1baf92;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.input__wrapper:after {
  content: "\f0ac";
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  font-size: 1.5625rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__bottom__wrapper">
  <div class="header__bottom">
    <div class="header__bottom__title">
      <span>FIND YOUR</span>
      <h2>HOLIDAYS</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="header__bottom__content">
      <span>Where</span>
      <div class="input__wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="distination" value="" placeholder="distination">
      </div>
      <label for=""></label>
      <span>When</span>
      <div class="input__wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="select date" value="" placeholder="select date">
      </div>
      <a href="#">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте для input__wrapper прописать position:relative

Comment: В каком браузере вы проверяете? У меня везде псевдоэлемент :after работает.